# MySites dedicated web app?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2013, can My Sites be setup in the same web app as SharePoint content, or is a seperate web app preferred?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, it totally depends on your needs and structure you have defined for your farm. If there aren't many web applications and you haven't reached the [limit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#WebApplication), i would always prefer to create My Sites on a different web applications. There are a couple of reasons i have in mind why we should choose a separate web application for My Sites.

**1.** **Manageability :** If you have to do a Web Application level operation and don't want it to be performed on normal Site Collections (not the Personal Sites), a separate web application will give you more freedom to do.

**2. Limitations :** A single content Database can [contain maximum 10,000 Site Collections](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#SiteCollection). Where 2,500 non-Personal site collections and 7,500 Personal Sites, or 10,000 Personal Sites alone could be in that content DB. If you want these site collections to be separated in another DB on the basis of its type, i don't think that is possible unless you do the manual work. On the other hand if you have a separate web application and content DB's for My Sites, all of your Personal Site Collections will be in separated DBs. This would be also helpful while upgrading to newer version of SharePoint and planning the content when you have it separately.

**3. User Experience:** I believe it gives users a good experience that they have a friendly URL to reach their own personal site. For example, a URL http://mysite.contoso.com gives a good feel than http://sharepoint.contoso.com/mysite/ URL.

There are a couple of benefits of keeping it one web application as well.

1. You have everything under one domain i.e http://sharepoint.contoso.com
2. If you have already reached the [web application limit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#WebApplication) then there is no choice other than to create My Sites under any existing web application.
3. Users have to login only one time in the web application.

Hope it will help you to make decision.